# How to explode arrays and insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need help exploding this array and insert the values into MySQL

```
 $ar =  Array ( [0] => Array ( [status] => 1 [message] => Successfully Validated! [id] => 17 [licence] => 9ETD-6X57-AWSJ [period] => 6 [user] => 0 ) [1] => 1 )
```

What I tried so far:

```
//print_r($ar);
    $categories = '';
$cats = explode(",", $ar);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $cat = trim($cat);
    $categories .= "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
}
```

My table structure (column definitions),

```
id | licence | period | no_users
---|---------|--------|----------
   |         |        |
```

But I have this error:

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\Users\HP\Desktop\phpdesktop\www\setup.php on line 118
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\Users\HP\Desktop\phpdesktop\www\setup.php on line 119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode` is for creating an array from a string. You already have an array, so you need to loop over its values. It's not clear whether you want to output the key or the value from your array, but this code will output both and you can decide which to use:

```
foreach ($ar as $values) {
    if (!is_array($values)) continue;
    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
        echo "$k: $v\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
status: 1
message: Successfully Validated!
id: 17 
licence: 9ETD-6X57-AWSJ 
period: 6 
user: 0
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/M65Qd)

**Update**

To insert into your table using PDO, assuming a connection called `$conn`, you might do something like this. First change the `foreach` loop to insert the values into an array, then prepare a statement and insert using the data array:

```
foreach ($ar as $values) {
    if (!is_array($values)) continue;
    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
        $data[":$k"] = $v;
    }
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (id, licence, period, no_users)
                        VALUES (:id, :licence, :period, :no_users)");
$stmt->execute($data);
```

I'm not sure how much PDO cares about extra parameters in the array as I've never tried it, but you might need to use

```
unset($data[':status'], $data[':message']);
```

to remove the unneeded values before the `execute`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. One more thing please, how can  I store the values in variables and insert into MySQL. I am new to php.

Comment: @OlajumokeAdemilade do you have a table set up in MySQL already? If so, what is its structure? Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: Yes, I have a table set up, pdo.

Comment: @OlajumokeAdemilade what is its structure (column definitions)? Can you add that information to your question (it's probably too big for a comment)

Comment: I have updated my question. The id is an auto increment.  Thanks.

Comment: @OlajumokeAdemilade I've updated my answer. You might need to make some minor modifications, but hopefully that will be enough to get you going,

Comment: @OlajumokeAdemilade no worries. Happy to help.